# Can't pass method print in java

Tags: java

So, I have a class with the following `main` method:

```
public class Game {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ball Game");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 550);

    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);  
  }

}
```

and a class with the method `print`:

```
public class Ball  {
  public void print(Graphics g) {
    g.fillOval(20, 20, 30, 30);  
  }
}
```

How can I pass the `print` method at the main class `Game`?
Sorry for my english, it isn't my first language.

Comment: On a point of nomenclature, "print" implies doing something with text. "draw" or "print" might be a better name.

Answer (score 0):

If your class `Ball` is in another file you will have to import the class.

In your `main`, you need to instantiate the class `Ball` as follow:

```
Ball b = new Ball();
```

Which will call the default constructor of the class `Ball` or a constructor you defined.

Then you can call your function `print` by doing:

```
b.print(g);
```

Assuming that g is an instance of `Graphics` class.

Comment: if i add "b.print(g)" it return an error "cannot find symbol. Symbol = variable g. Location = Game"

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `print` method static.

like this

```
public static void print(Graphics g){...}
```

Then call it like this `Ball.print(g)` (assuming that g is instance of `Graphics`)

Comment: I'll try. Thanks